# How to display rounded corners in a highcharts column on a Y Axis that starts above 0

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For the following Highcharts chart, I am using the official rounded corners plugin to round all four corners of each column, as so:

**Image 1**
[image]

However when the scale values are adjusted, to begin with a value that is greater than zero, the following occurs:

**Image 2**
[image]

I am looking for a workaround so that instead of the corners being cut off in image 2, the bottom of the column starts from the beginning of the y-axis, just like image 1.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

- If the min (smallest) value of the [yAxis.tickpositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions) array is greater than 0, then add an additional series of the value min to the y axis.
- If the min value is 0 then make this value 0.

Comment: yAxis.min didn't helped you? You may set this value smaller than 0

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński not for my use case. However I didn't try this approach it may work